The name of mapping between two line segments within a cone?
In both graphs, the blue line segment is mapped to the red line segment (for any point on the blue line, connect it with the black point, and extend it to intersect with the red line. The intersection point is the image of this mapping). The two lines are parallel in the first graph but not in the second.
I was wondering whether the first is called "affine transformation" and the second is called "collineation" (1). Or is there a more specific name for such mappings within a cone?


